# Is it against code to run electric Line in cpvc out of breaker panel and into the ground?

Tags: electrical

Electric question, Is it code in Az to run an electric line in cpvc out of breaker panel into the ground and to destination

Answer (score 2):

You have to use conduit listed and labeled for electrical use. So if you're thinking about using plumbing pipe, forget about it.

Since the conduit will be underground, it's considered a wet location. That means you'll have to  use wires that are allowed in wet locations. THWN is commonly used for this, though is likely advertised as THHN/THWN or THWN-2, or something similar.

Wherever you enter/exit the ground, you'll want to use an expansion fitting. This allows the conduit to expand and contract, as well as allowing the ground to heave and depress as soil conditions change.

Comment: Can you imagine trying to pull cable around a corner in plumbing pipe?  That's a great example of what "listed" means, the plumbing pipe isn't designed to not have burrs that would snag or tear the cable.

Comment: CPVC would be a night mare and tear the insulation + tester. Depending on the length a expansion fitting may not be needed.

Comment: I've seen installs where people skipped the expansion fitting neatly broken at the nearest joint. When the ground containing the conduit moves with frost, there is immense force applied. I'm not too happy with how much expansion fittings cost (nor with how paltry the selection is at home cheapo) but I use them somewhat religiously, and don't have broken conduits. In most cases you also need to use schedule 80 for PVC conduit, since conduit from the box into the ground is considered "exposed to damage" - and home cheapo doesn't have much, if any, of that, either.

Comment: @Ecnerwal commonly held myth, that the big box stores are cheap.   What they are is "open til 9", and they exploit that in their pricing.  Electricians who do a ton of work and deal in volume, drive right past 3 big box stores on their way to a proper electrical supply house.   But don't be the guy who only goes to the electrical supply for the one part big-box doesn't have, get to know them and make them a regular source.

Comment: Since the latest topic is price I was thinking and checked home desperate. [cpvc](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Charlotte-Pipe-1-2-in-x-10-ft-CPVC-SDR11-Flowguard-Gold-Pipe-CTS-12005-0600/100170202) at 3.91$ stick. 1/2" schedule [40 conduit](http://www.homedepot.com/p/JM-eagle-1-2-in-x-10-ft-PVC-Schedule-40-Conduit-67447/100122861) 1.71$ they Did not show/ not carry schedule 80 in 1/2- 3/4- or 1" that I could see.  Platt carry's 1/2" schedule 80 for 3.11$ per stick, so CPVC would be way more expensive. The OP is from a warmer climate and may need an expansion. I not had a pullout or broken pipe